# What's Happening When Lerping Using Time.deltaTime?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, time, lerp

I've just recently been introduced to `Time.deltaTime` and lerping and have been kinda stuck for the past few days.

So when I plug in `Time.deltaTime` for the last `float` and then multiply by another float variable called `speed`, what exactly is happening? What is `Time.deltaTime` doing to `speed` each frame that gives the end result?

Thank you!!

```
public class CameraMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject followTarget;
    public float moveSpeed;

    void Update()
    {
        if (followTarget != null)
        {
            transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, followTarget.transform.position, moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime); 
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[`Vector3.Lerp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html)  expects a factor between `0` and `1` and interpolates the two positions so

- `0` would mean `transform.position`
- `1` would mean `followTarget.transform.position`

any other value between those the interpolation between them meaning something like

```
transform.position + (followTarget.transform.position - transform.position) * factor;
```

---

[`Time.deltaTime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html) = `time past since last frame rendered` so most likely a value close to `0.017` (for 60FPS). You can calculate by yourself what value this gives you in average for `moveSpeed * 0.017`.

---

It looks like what you are actually looking for is rather [`Vector3.MoveTowards`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.MoveTowards.html)

```
void Update()
{
    if (followTarget != null)
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, followTarget.transform.position, moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime); 
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Time.deltaTime * scalar` in Lerp is perfectly fine, but it's not the "expected" way to use it.

LERP means "Linear intERPolation". With this mathematic tool, you are able to *interpolate* a value between two others using a linear function ( y = ax + b ) and a coefficient t between 0 and 1.

Supposing you are trying to get a position (C) between two others (A and B) (like your problem), you have the folowing drawing :

[image]

**1°) If the initial and destination position does not change, having the parameter t vary between 0 and 1, the movement curve will be perfectly straight : the speed will be the same over time.**

```
transform.position = Vector2.Lerp(InitialPosition, DestinationPosition, t ); // t from 0 to 1
```

**2°) However, having t (almost) not vary over time (with `Time.deltaTime`), but chaning the position of A, the movement will decelerate over time, because you take a fixed percentage of the remaining distance each time. Since the distance decrease over time, you travel less distance over time too**

```
transform.position = Vector2.Lerp(transform.position, DestinationPosition, 0.017 ); // 0.017, approx of Time.deltaTime at 60FPS
```

[image]